# How to release game UIView and go back to the root menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ipad, delegates

for example , when you playing game , you are play in the game UIView

and when you exit your game and return to the game root menu,

there're a 'exit' button on the game UIView

I wanna click this button to release self view and go back to the main menu

how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your game `UIView` is owned by a `UIViewController` ? Then just add a button to the view and hook it up to an `IBAction` in the `UIViewController` that pops or dismisses the view controller.

Comment: My game structure like this:

 - GameRootMenu(UIVIew)

    -ChapterChoose(UIView)

      -eachChapterGame(UIView);
 
when exit form "eachChapterGame" ,I wanna release this chapter's UIView and all scence and element in this chapter 


I use the a button to remove this chapter view from super view (to root Menu),but not release, and recieve the memory warning


and I try to release it on the super view ,it crashed,


how to do this?